# rxjs catcherror appening before pipe

Tags: rxjs

I found some strange behavior on rxjs and I want to know if it's the expected behavior or if I missed something (I use angular but I thing it's not related) :

```
public someFunction() {

    // this woks as expected: log "test1"
    return of(null).pipe(
        switchMap(() => this.errorTest()),
        catchError((e: Error) => {
            console.log('test1');
            return throwError(e);
        })
    );

    // "test2" is never logged
    return this.errorTest().pipe(
        catchError((e: Error) => {
            console.log('test2');
            return throwError(e);
        })
    );
}

private errorTest(): Observable<any> {
    throw Error('one error');
}
```

when I subscribe someFunction the first function logs "test1", but the second doesn't log anything, error is no catched...

Answer (score 1):

```js
private errorTest(): Observable<any> {
    throw Error('one error');
}
```

Does **not** return an observable.

```js
switchMap(() => this.errorTest())
```

Catches **errors** from the callback function.

```js
switchMap(() => throw Error('one error'))
```

Is the same as your example, and `this.errorTest().pipe()` never **returns** so you don't get an error for trying to call `.pipe()` on *undefined*.

What you wanted to do was this.

```js
private errorTest(): Observable<any> {
    return throwError(new Error('one error'));
}
```

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/throwError